# The search button on Jobs is disabled if you use the back button

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I performed the following actions on Jobs

- Click in Location box
- Toggle "Allow Remote"
- Click search

At this point, I noticed a job that looked interested. The results of my search then loaded before I could click. I pressed by back button and the Search button was disabled.

[image: Disabled Search button]

The button doesn't re-enable if I fill in a location or a keyword. I need to refresh the page for the button to be active again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got rid of quite a bit of the AJAX weirdness in the search form some time ago and that appears to have fixed this, at least I can't repro it.

Drop a comment if you the issue rears its head again!